# How to execute a script when a volume is mounted in macOS

Tags: macos, backup, mount, time-machine

I have used [this technique](https://www.berserkcomputers.co.uk/blogs/post/how-to-save-apple-time-machine-backups-to-cloud-services-like-onedrive) to back up my Time Machine backups to my Google Drive. I have a couple of issues remaining, and one of them is around automatically mounting my encrypted virtual Time Machine drive when my external drive volume, where this virtual drive is stored, is mounted.

Is it possible to have a script run automatically when a volume is mounted in macOS? This script will just mount the virtual drive. I saw one or two posts on this site around this, but the links were out of date.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't rely on external links to explain what you are doing. Use the EDIT button and include the specific things you've done here in the body of the question. You can use a link to provide attribution or for extra information, but it should not be necessary to read an external source to understand what you are trying to tell us.

Comment: Roger that,....

Comment: Here, let me Google that for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+trigger+when+drive+plugged+in&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS929US929&oq=macos+trigger+when+drive+plugged+in&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.7782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8